# rectangle 720px is only half visible on phone 720 x 1280

Tags: html, css, viewport

my phone is Huawei cun-L01
specifications says - display: 720 x 1280 px
on a page I have a rectangle - 720 px width
it is not entire visible
in fact - only 360 px width is visible entirely (half of 720)
here is my meta viewport

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```

should I change `initial scale` (in that case viewport on a desktop display will not be correct)

what is the best practice here?

here is a live example - https://abuena.net/test.php

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the `meta` tag to this; let me know how it goes:
`<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width"/>`

I believe your issue might be related to no 'minimum-scale' being set within the `meta` tag. Thanks again, let me know how this goes :)

Comment: the same result. here is a live example - `https://abuena.net/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

Your base viewport size is 1280x720px and you can declare it with a meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=720, height=1280">
```

this problem happens due to *different pixel densities on smartphones* and [this amazing article](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/using-css3-units-support-low-and-high-density-screens) takes the subject into account and looks at it from different points of view. you can check that for further readings

Comment: based on your link - does that mean that javascript is a must - to see an element properly on all devices?

Comment: @qadenza It's of course better to use a mixture of css relative Lengths and media queries to have a neat responsive page, and you can do it using different methods based on what you expect. adding the mentioned meta tag just solved the issue you wanted to solve. you certainly need to use more css and js to get the desired results as you wish.